# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited

Tags: python, django

```
(ll_env) brads-MacBook-Pro:learning_log $ python manage.py runserver
    Performing system checks...
    
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10d417d08>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/learning_log/learning_log/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
        url(r'',include('learning_logs.urls',namespace='learning_logs')),
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/learning_log/learning_logs/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
        from . import views
      File "/learning_log/learning_logs/views.py", line 6, in <module>
        from .forms import TopicForm
      File "/learning_log/learning_logs/forms.py", line 4, in <module>
        class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
      File "/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 243, in __new__
        "needs updating." % name
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form TopicForm needs updating.
```

**some part of the code**:

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'learning_log.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topic
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
#from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.urls import reverse
from .forms import TopicForm
    
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    topics=Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context={'topics':topics}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topics.html',context)
    
def topic(request,topic_id):
    topic=Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries=topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context={'topic':topic,'entries':entries}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topic.html',context)
    
def new_topic(request): 
    if request.method != 'POST': 
        form = TopicForm()
    else: 
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))
    
    context = {'form',form}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/new_topic.html',context)
```

So, I'ver been learning Python using the book *Python Crash Course: A hands-on, Project-Based Introduction to Programming*. And when I 'runserver', it just showed the above error. I don't know what was wrong, because I did exactly what the book says. Can anybody help me out?

what happened when I try the above steps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put your TopicForm also

Comment: And also, please put your  learning_logs.urls

Answer (score 27):

When you are creating a form using model, you need to specify which fields you want to be included in the form.

For example you have a model with the named Article and you want to create a form for the model article.

pub_date, headline, content, reporter these are the fields in the model.
If you choose to include all the fields you do like this.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you want to specify which fields you want to include

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content']
```

If you want to exclude a certain fields and use the remaining then use as follows

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = ['headline']
```

Coming to your error, it says you can use ModelForm with out using one of the two options that is using fields or exclude.

Comment: Thank you, got it. It is enlightening.

Comment: Link to docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

Answer (score 6):

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = '__all__' # or whatever fields you want ('field_a', )
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Actually, I had a few typos  also.
But I had this problem occurring when I runserver again that it doesn't show a submit button since I had:

  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method='post'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <button name="submit">add topic</button>
  </form>

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same error and turns out I had written 'field' instead of 'fields
'

Answer (score 2):

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Blog
        fields='__all__'
```

check name `fields`, you type incorrectly, or capital F is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import forms
from .models import Dforms

class Forms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dforms
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: Please add some sort of explanation for your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my mistake was to miss the name of a class in my app's forms.py file

Answer (score -1):

i had aslo same problem after i checked my code again then i find i had written `field` istead of `fields` so first check name fields, you may have type incorrectly.