# class Meta VS form fields in Django

Tags: django, forms

I'm learning Django forms from [this](https://djangobook.com/mdj2-django-forms/) example. When I run my server I get `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited` (solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734479/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-creating-a-modelform-without-either/51734654)). Using class Meta everything works.
Explain pliese could I use these both aproaches with `Django==2.2.6` and pros and cons of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Django 1.8, it was required that forms explicitly indicate which fields they wanted to display in class Meta, so you definitely need to do it in 2.2.6.

`fields` is an inclusive way to listing fields. If you explicitly want to list which fields are included in the form, you put them here. This means that if you ever change your model, the new fields in the model will not automatically be added to the form unless you set fields to `__all__`

`exclude` is unsurprisingly the opposite of that. It means that the form includes all fields except those explicitly listed in exclude. If you change your model, new fields will be added to the form unless you change what is in `exclude`.

The differences are not really that large in the grand scheme of things. It just depends on whether you want to explicitly specify what is included or what is excluded.