# Submitting form without refreshing page using Django, Ajax, jQuery?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am a newbie working with Django. I need a simple example. How to submit the form (post) without refreshing page using Django, Ajax, jQuery?

This is my form, views, and template:

views.py

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import *
from django.template import RequestContext
from linnea.web_interface import run_linnea 
from linnea_demo_app.forms import *

def linnea_demo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AdvertForm(request.POST)

        message = 'something wrong!'
        if(form.is_valid()):
            print(request.POST['title'])
            message = request.POST['title']

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))

    return render_to_response('linnea_demo.html',
            {'form':AdvertForm()}, RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from linnea_demo_app.models import Advert

class AdvertForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Advert
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Advert(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
```

index.html

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="post-form">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {{form.as_p}}
                  <input type="submit" id="btnGetKernel" class="" value="Generate Kernel"/>
              </form>
```

.js

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    $.post('/url/', $(this).serialize(), function(data){ 
       $('.message').html(data.message);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

However, I got this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form AdvertForm needs updating.

am I doing it right?

Comment: Two seconds Googling the error message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734761/519413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is extremely clear.

> Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form AdvertForm needs updating.

You need to update `AdvertForm` to include either a `fields` or `exclude` attribute.

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from linnea_demo_app.models import Advert

class AdvertForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Advert
        fields = ['text']
```